# A better way to alternate a character in loop

Tags: ruby, loops, alternating

I have a loop that should change the referent of the variable `dot` from a period to a space every time it repeats:

```
dot = (dot == ".") ? " " : "."
```

This works fine, but it doesn't read like proper Ruby to me. It seems like this should be a one line statement. I am wondering if there is a more Ruby-like way to accomplish this. I'm open to a different way to accomplish this in a loop; Possibly `gsub` could do it.

Comment: This smells like an XY-problem. Presenting more context for the problem will make is possible to give better answers.

Comment: For the curious: [The XY problem is asking about your attempted *solution* rather than your *actual problem*.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/220858)

Comment: @Substantial Thanks for clarifying what XY problems are. I don't think this is an XY problem because I am looking for "grammar" help with Ruby - what is the right way to solve a well-defined problem in the Ruby, rather than limiting context. Notably sawa heavily edited my question removing a ton of context which would make the question even less XY-like. And cary-swoveland gave a perfect answer so thanks to him for that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dot = [' ', '.'].cycle
  #=> #<Enumerator: [" ", "."]:cycle>

dot.next #=> " "
dot.next #=> "."
dot.next #=> " "
dot.next #=> "."
```

Comment: Exactly the rubyism I suspected existed but didn't know about. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
dot.gsub(/[\. ]/, '.' => ' ', ' ' => '.')
```

Which means:

Look for `.` or `space` and replace with `space` and `.`

Answer (score 1):

If your loop is one of the standard forms, you can use #with_index or its variants:

```
objects.each_with_index do |element, index|
   separator = index.even? ? "." : " "
   ... do something with element and separator
end
```

This makes the intention explicit, which generally trumps clever coding.